# Changing the HTTP port for Oracle ORDS 2

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-ords

I am being told by my DBA's that I cannot change the HTTP port that my APEX service is listening on, and will require a fresh reinstallation of ORDS, possibly upgrading to ORDS 3 which is supported by Oracle.  But I was also told, this reinstallation of ORDS (either 2 or 3) will require my instance of Oracle to be rebuilt.

I am not a DBA, I am an Apex workspace administrator and business owner of the 11GR2 Oracle instance.  I do not believe that we cannot simply change the HTTP port through some configuration and then restart a service.

Also, I do not believe that we cannot install/upgrade ORDS 3.0 over the top of ORDS 2, or reinstall ORDS 2, without scrapping and rebuilding the entire Oracle instance.

Especially when I see articles such as this:

https://blog.cdivilly.com/2015/03/11/install-ords-3.0.0/

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E56351_01/doc.30/e56293/install.htm#AELIG-GUID-BEF8B58F-53C2-4377-AC38-595A85094E79

Can anyone advise, when using Oracle 11GR2, how to configure the APEX http port or ORDS 2, and whether it is feasible to upgrade to ORDS 3 and APEX 5 (from ORDS 2 and APEX 4.2) without major impact to the instance and existing data/applications.

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: I think you need a new DBA.

Comment: upgrade from apex 4 to apex 5 should be close to seamless, the applications will be ok but you might want to tweak some look and feel stuff to take advantage of apex 5 features/improvements. you can upgrade ords from 2 to 3 with no impact to the db really, although ords 3 has it's own db repository/metadata schema - and you have the option of migrating your apex defined restful services into ords repo or not

Comment: absolutely no need to scrap/rebuild the entire Oracle Instance - that's a pretty crazy statement and wondering where that's coming from

Comment: Hi,  any advice on a simple http port reconfiguration - I am assuming this also does not require a fresh ORDS installation but can be tweaked post installation.

Comment: How is your ORDS deployed? Standalone, Tomcat, Glassfish?

Comment: Let me find out @Rene, as I say I am not the DBA just a lowly workspace administrator

Answer (score 4):

You can:

1)  Easily change the HTTP port that is running ORDS.  It all depends on what Java container you're using to run ORDS.  If it's Apache Tomcat of the built-in HTTP listener or ORDS, for example, then it's downright trivial to change the HTTP port.  If it's Glassfish or WLS, then it's only slightly more complicated.

2)  Run separate deployments of ORDS 2 and ORDS 3 concurrently.  And you could run multiple deployments of ORDS 3 concurrently, if you wished.  They could stand up ORDS 3 adjacent to ORDS 2 so you could test and assess the impact.

Upgrading from ORDS 2 to ORDS 3 will not require a rebuild of the Oracle Database at all.  And upgrading from APEX 4 to APEX 5 will also not require a rebuild of the Oracle Database.  It should all be seamless to you and your APEX applications.